# Stub 'require' to throw error using 'testdouble'

Tags: node.js, npm, test-double

I want to stub the 'require' call to a module to throw error. Is there a way to do it using 'testdouble' or 'proxyrequire'?

Comment: Yes, there are dedicated solutions, for example _proxyquire_, and general solutions that allow remapping graphs relative to arbitrarily specific packages, for example _SystemJS_.